# How to create a dictionary in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am newbie in python, want to create a new dictionary in a for loop.
For example:

```
for x in data:
    a_data = x.a
    model_obj = modelname.objects.get(id=x.b)
    b_data = model_obj.address
    c_data = x.c
    d_data = x.d
```

I want to create a dictionary which should work as for the first iteration

```
'a_data': x.a
'b_data':model_obj.address
'c_data':x.c
'd_data':x.d
```

and so on for the next iteration. I think we can works with : `list of dictioanry` or `dictionary of dictionary`. I even don't know which one is better. I have to render this data to a template.

Any help will be appreciable :)

Comment: What's expected in next iterations? You want list of dicts?

Comment: In the second iteration it will print the x[1] and then x[2] in the same order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
listofobjs = []
for x in data:
    d = {
      'a_data': x.a,
      'b_data':model_obj.address,
      'c_data':x.c,
      'd_data':x.d,
    }
    listofobjs.append(d)
```